# Stringify data from a map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, parsing, dictionary

The end goal is to input a massive txt file and replace all words as given in a csv file. A new txt file would be created alongside a new csv file that counted the number of occurences of each word.

What I'm having issues with is to write the map data to a new csv file. I get that the data is undefined, but how do I change it to be readable?

No matter what kind of map.thingie I put into the data.push field, I get an error.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var inputFile='OneLetter.csv';
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var map1 = new Map();
var iterator = map1[Symbol.iterator]();


//This part creates a stream, essentially reads it and creates a list

var parser = parse({delimiter: ';'}, function (err, data) {
    data.forEach(function(line) {
      // create line object out of parsed fields
      var list = map1.set(line) 
     });
        for (let item of iterator) {
    console.log(item)
    };    
});

fs.createReadStream(inputFile).pipe(parser);


//This program writes a CSV file containing data in the data1, data2... fields

let data = [];
let columns = {
        Column1: '# times',
        Column2: 'Original',
        Column3: 'Short'
};

  data.push(['data1',
             'data2',
             'data3'
]); 

var stringify = require('csv-stringify');

stringify(data ,{ delimiter: ';', header: true, columns: columns }, (err, output) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  fs.writeFile('TEST.csv', output, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('TEST.csv saved.');
  });
});

Working Result:

[ [ 'A', 'A' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'B', 'BE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'C', 'SEE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'D', 'IN THE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'E', 'HE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'F', 'OF THE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'G', 'FROM THE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'H', 'HAS' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'I', 'I' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'J', 'BY WHICH' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'K', 'OUT OF THE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'L', 'ALL' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'M', 'MORE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'N', 'NOT' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'O', 'OF' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'P', 'PER' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'Q', 'ON THE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'R', 'ARE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'S', 'SEPERATOR' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'T', 'THE' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'U', 'YOU' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'V', 'OF WHICH' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'W', 'WITH' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'X', 'IN WHICH' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'Y', 'YES' ], undefined ]
[ [ 'Z', 'FROM WHICH' ], undefined ]
TEST.csv saved.
```

Non-Working Result:

```
Error: Invalid Record: expect an array or an object, got undefined
    at Stringifier._transform (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\csv-stringify\lib\index.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to see an option to transform in `parse` method according to the docs - you would need to try to use [transform](https://csv.js.org/transform/api/) to have it work the way you want - so create one and pass it like this:

```
const transformer = transform(function(data){
    return replaceEntries(data); // here you call the replacement
});
fs.createReadStream(textFile).pipe(parser).pipe(transformer).pipe(stringify);
```

The transformer needs to be prepared prior to

Judging by your case it seems that passing a transform function is not documented and the error may come from that... Additionally your code doesn't seem to be doing what you're trying to achieve, more like you're trying to create a new CSV.

I think you may have started the task from a strange angle so I'd advise you to redo from start - what you need is to write a program that does the following in the following order:

1. Read the CSV file to memory and create a map or array of replacements
2. Create a readable stream from the TXT file
3. Create a transform stream and pipe the readable to it
4. Create a writable stream and pipe the transform to it

I can also suggest using the [scramjet](https://www.scramjet.org/) framework, that I created, which may make the code easier and more understandable:

```
const {StringStream} = require("scramjet");

StringStream
    // here we read the file
    .from(fs.createReadStream('massive.txt'))
    .use(async stream => {
        // here we create replacements
        const replacements = await (
            StringStream.from(fs.createReadStream('massive.txt'))
                .csvParse({header: false})
                // the line below will make sure we're replacing whole words
                .map(([_from, _to]) => ([new RegExp(`\b${_from}\b`, "g"), _to])
                .toArray()
        );

        // here we map all the items in the stream and iterate over all the replacements
        return stream.map(
            chunk => replacements.reduce((s, [_from, _to]) => s.replace(_from, _to), chunk)
        );
    })
    // and here we push the replaced stream to the output file
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('massive-file-out.txt');
```

Please check the line that starts with `.map(([_from, _to]) =>`. I'm assuming that you want to replace the text only if it's a whole word, so more `R U ready -> Are you ready`, not `Robert -> Areobert` - that's the purpose of this line.

Comment: Im sorry, but I don't know how to use this code properly. It would probably help to know what ([new RegExp(`\b${_from}\b`, "g"), _to]) does. Also, before the map data wasn't loaded as seperate key/values, but I fixed it now. I do not read anywhere in the code above where it takes key/values from the map previously created, rather it makes a new map. Also you missed a few ) here and there, which I fixed.

Comment: I'll create a repo on github and post the working example. As to the RegExp - this is a regular expression that matches whole words.